# Autohotkey Not sending keys in the wrong order

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I have the script:

```
#F20:: ^!{DEL}
```

which is suppose to simulate pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd>"
I Viewed the event log and the order in which the keys simulations are sent is completely messed up! What have i done wrong and how can i achieve the desired affect?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just did some digging, unfortunately Windows does not allow for simulation of Ctrl + Alt + Del. If you want the task manager it brings up simply use:

```
#F20::Run taskmgr
```

Answer (score 0):

As ahkcoder pointed out Windows keeps Ctrl+Alt+Del out of reach, see
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Remarks
Apart from that the order of your key history is correct. It's just interspersed with other keys you pressed, likely because your script uses the keyboard hook. 
Which in turn would prevent your #F20 Hotkey to work if it is itself triggered from a script. Without seeing your actual script that's about as much as i can think of.